Joule expansion: Experimental evidence for temperature change
In his original experiment, Joule found that there was no change in temperature after releasing air from one volume into a larger one [1]. However, we know now that for real gases there should be cooling due to attractive van der Waals interactions. The difficulty is that this change in temperature is very tricky to resolve - for hundreds of liters of air and doubling the volume upon expansion the change in temperature is just a few Kelvin. In many textbooks I see this statement that there is cooling [2], but I have not found experimental evidence (neither with classical nor quatum gases) for this. I know that this is a rather trivial effect, but I wonder if there have been any experimental verifications?

Would you accept the Joule-Thomson experiments instead? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect

No, sorry, I mean specificially Joule expansion. I am aware that there is an abundance of JT experiments, which is why I am specifically interested in Joule experiments as there appears to be a lack of experimental studies...

Well, there are an abundance of JT experiments precisely because they are easier to do and get good measurements, yet are driven by the same physics.

That I am aware of - which is precisely the reason why I am looking for Joule expansion experiments: It is more difficult but should certainly be possible with today's technology (compared to Joule's original experiment in 1845 with copper insulation and water to measure the temperature). However, I did not find a single one. Even just for a proof of principle?
